# Border Color for Editor in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can i make a border color for Editor in Xamarin.Forms?

I used this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/845894/How-to-make-EditText-With-Border-and-Gradient-Back), but it works only for Android. I want it to work in all platforms!

I'm a little bit newbie to this.
Please help me.

Any idea?

Answer (score 44):

You may also archieve this by wrapping your Editor with a `StackLayout` with `BackgroundColor="your color"` and `Padding="1"` and set the `BackgroundColor` of your Editor to the same color of the form.

Something like this:

> ```
> <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
>       <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="1">
>           <Editor BackgroundColor="White" />
>       </StackLayout>
>   ...
> </StackLayout>
> ```

Not that fancy, but this will at least get you a border!

Comment: Not fancy indeed, but fast enough for the generic client who wants his app for yesterday.

Answer (score 32):

Here's the complete solution I used. You need three things.

1 - A custom class that implements `Editor` in your forms project.

```
public class BorderedEditor : Editor
{

}
```

2 - A custom renderer for your custom `Editor` in your iOS project.

```
public class BorderedEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 3;
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("F0F0F0").ToCGColor();
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

3 - An `ExportRenderer` attribute in your iOS project that tells Xamarin to use your custom renderer for your custom editor.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderedEditor), typeof(BorderedEditorRenderer))]
```

Then use your custom editor in Xaml:

```
<custom:BorderedEditor Text="{Binding TextValue}"/>
```

Comment: Note that the "custom" entry in <custom:BorderedEditor... is the name associated with your PCL project namespace.  So, for this to work as written, you would have to have a reference in your <ContentPage tag of xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:<project_name>".  Since using "local" is more common for the namespace reference, you may want to use that instead; e.g., <local:BorderedEditor...

Comment: CornerRadius 6, BorderColor LightGray, and BorderWidth .5f better matches the default border for Entry.

Comment: A little more explanation and this answer would be pretty good for a blog's entry!

Comment: As @EdwardBrey told, it better matches the default look of iOS with a Border set to 6 and and a border width set to 0.5f.
Thank you Edward

Comment: Try the color #cccccc because it is more accurate than LightGray.

Comment: For a perfect match use color #CECECE with BorderWidth = 1.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way is to add a frame around it.

```
 <Frame BorderColor="LightGray" HasShadow="False" Padding="0">
     <Editor/>
 </Frame>
```

Answer (score 5):

**in your portable project add this control**

```
 public class PlaceholderEditor : Editor
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Placeholder", typeof(string), typeof(string), "");

    public PlaceholderEditor()
    {
    }

    public string Placeholder
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value);
        }
    }       
}
```

**in your android project add this renderer:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PlaceholderEditor), typeof(PlaceholderEditorRenderer))]
namespace Tevel.Mobile.Packages.Droid
{


public class PlaceholderEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{ 

public PlaceholderEditorRenderer() {  }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var element = e.NewElement as PlaceholderEditor;

            this.Control.Background = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.borderEditText);

            this.Control.Hint = element.Placeholder;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == PlaceholderEditor.PlaceholderProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var element = this.Element as PlaceholderEditor;
            this.Control.Hint = element.Placeholder;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**in your Resources > drawable add an XML file borderEditText.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:angle="270" />
  <stroke
      android:width="3dp"
      android:color="#F8B334" />
  <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
  </item>
  <item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#FFFFFF"  android:angle="270" />
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ccc" />
  <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

**Xaml:**
Header - `xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:my control namespace;assembly= my assembly"`
control:

```
<ctrls:PlaceholderEditor VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Placeholder="add my comment title">
        </ctrls:PlaceholderEditor>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement a `Custom Renderer` ([guide from Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)) for each platform since customizing the `BorderColor` of an `Entry` is not yet supported in `Xamarin.Forms`.

Since you've already managed to change the `BorderColor` on Android, you can find a solution for iOS here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/102557/#Comment_102557

Answer (score 0):

This works for sure, try this.

**Android Renderer**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Graphics;

    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(some.namespace.EntryRenderer))]
    namespace some.namespace
    {
        public class EntryRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.EntryRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (Control == null || Element == null || e.OldElement != null) return;

                var customColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#0F9D58");
                Control.Background.SetColorFilter(customColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way to android renderer

```
if (((Editor)Element).HasBorder)
                {
                    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                    gd.SetColor(Android.Resource.Color.HoloRedDark);
                    gd.SetCornerRadius(4);
                    gd.SetStroke(2, Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray);
                    Control.SetBackground(gd);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a Custom Control as a Grid. Build BoxViews around it and place the Editor in the middle with margin.
Not nice but simple...

```
    <Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace:xxx.CustomControls"
             x:Class="xxx.CustomControls.EditorWithBorder" BackgroundColor="White"
                x:Name="this">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinitionCollection>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
        </RowDefinitionCollection>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinitionCollection>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
        </ColumnDefinitionCollection>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Editor Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this},Path=EditorText, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Orange" Margin="20,10,20,10" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLarge}"
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />


    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Orange"
             ></BoxView>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Orange"

             ></BoxView>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Orange" HeightRequest="1"

             ></BoxView>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Orange" HeightRequest="1"

             ></BoxView>
</Grid>
```